# What does it mean that Array.prototype.sort "[compares] strings in UTF-16 code units order"?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I'm learning about the Array.prototype.sort() in Javascript, and in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort , it explains that if no *comparaFunction* argument is passed, it will convert the values into strings and compare them in UTF-16 code units order.

For example,

```
"2" > "15" => true
```

Can someone explain me how this statement is true using UTF-16 code units of order. Are UTF-8 code units different? I thought UTF-X are just encoders and follow the unicode - code units (aka code points) for everything. My question is why does MDN says "UTF-16"?

Comment: It means you convert each character to its UTF-16 character code, then compare those codes numerically.

Comment: can you provide an example of the translation? Because UTF-16 is just an encoder and is different than the unicode code points.

Comment: @Barmar was going to say this and add [this link](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm) to show what those codes are. But yes: take a character -> convert to the code point -> compare. For alphanumerical characters, the order is *mostly* logical (outside the `"2" > "15"` numeric ones) but then you get stuff like spaces and other characters (`+`, `=`, `:`, `@`, etc) that have a set order but it's not easy to just guess what it is, outside of looking it up.

Answer (score 4):

The string `"2"` is the following sequence of character codes:

```
50
```

The string `"15"` is:

```
49 53
```

Comparing the string means comparing the character codes sequentially, stopping when you get the first difference (if you reach the end of both strings with no difference, the strings are equal). Since `50 > 49`, we stop at the first character and return the result of that comparison.

These characters have the same codes in UTF-16 as they do in UTF-8 (this is true for all the basic ASCII characters), so the difference between those coding systems is irrelevant for this example.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I agree with what you said and I thought the same thing too. I got confused by what MDN says " UTF-16 code units" and I thought that encoders has nothing to do with the comparison. I should have clarify my question to be clearer.